# If $\rho$ is a mod $p$ irreducible representation of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, why is it tamely ramified?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification, galois-representations

Fix a prime $p$ and let $\rho:G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}\rightarrow GL_2(\overline {\mathbb{F}}_p)$ be an arbitrary continuous representation. I found the following statement in a paper on non-ordinary modular forms: *If $\rho$ is irreducible then $\rho|_{I_p}$ is tamely ramified*, where $I_p$ is the inertia subgroup of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$.

I honestly am not sure exactly what the definition of tamely ramified is in this setting, but since the image of $\rho$ is finite (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522713/why-is-the-image-of-a-pmod-p-galois-representation-finite/3650075#3650075)), I assume it means that the order of the image is prime to $p$.

Here are some thoughts. We have the following exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow I_{p,w}\rightarrow I_p\rightarrow I_{p,t}\rightarrow 1
$$
where the $w$ and $t$ subscripts denote the wild ramification group and the tame quotient, respectively. Hence, if (for some reason) $I_{p,w}$ were equal to the kernel of $\rho|_{I_p}$, then the image would be isomorphic to $I_{p,t}= I_p/I_{p,w}$, which has order prime to $p$. I'm not sure why this would be true though, and am not sure why irreducibility would be important here.

Comment: "Tamely ramified" means that the fixed field of the kernel is a tamely ramified extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$; equivalently, the image of wild inertia $I_{p,w}$ under $\rho$ is trivial. Denote the image by $G$ and the image of $I_{p,w}$ by $H$, and the underlying vector space on which $\rho$ acts by $V$. Since $H$ is a p-group, $V^H$ is non-trivial. Since $H$ is normal, $V^{H}$ is invariant by $G$. Hence either $V^H = V$ and $H$ is trivial and $\rho$ is tamely ramified, or $V^{H}$ is a proper subspace invariant under $G$ and $V$ is reducible.

Comment: Thanks so much, that really clears things up for me. If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @user760870 Why $H$ p-group implies $V^H$ contains a non-zero $v$ ?

Comment: @reuns: you can see this in many ways, for example, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem the number of fixed points of $H$ is divisible by $p$ ($\rho$ is defined over a finite field).

Comment: $V$ has $p^n$ elements (with $n\ge 1$), $0$ is alone, if no non-zero $v$ is fixed by $H$ then $p$ would divide $|Hv|$ for each $v\ne 0\in V$ and since $p^n-1 = \sum_{Hv} |Hv|$ it would imply that $p |p^n-1$.

Comment: Isn't $V$ infinite here?

Comment: $\rho$ has finite image, so it is defined over a finite field $\mathbf{F}$ (just look at the entries of the coefficients of $\rho(g)$ for each $g \in G$ if you like) and then $G$ acts on $\mathbf{F}^n$. (If $V_{\mathbf{F}}$ is that representation, then obviously $V = V_{\mathbf{F}} \otimes \overline{\mathbf{F}}$). Anyway, I already mentioned this in my comment => "($\rho$ is defined over a finite field)".